# Cómo puedo comprobar contenido Array bidimensional JAVA

Tags: java

estoy haciendo un tres en raya con *java*, pero no sé cómo puedo comprobar si tiene 3 fichas iguales de forma horizontal o vertical. Estoy usando un **for** y un **if**, ahí es donde me quedo, ¿podríais decirme qué hacer o mandarme algún enlace? Gracias (hay cosas que fallan o no están bien definidas, a esas no les hagáis caso).

**Código:**

```
    package TresEnRaya;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Juego {

    private String jugador, ficha;
    private String[][] tablero = new String[3][3];
    private int fila, columna;

    //Crea y dibuja el tablero
    protected String[][] CrearTablero() {

        for (int columna=0; columna<tablero.length; columna++) {
            for (int fila=0; fila<tablero.length; fila++) {
                tablero[columna][fila] = "·";
                System.out.print(tablero[columna][fila] +" ");
            }
        System.out.println("");}
        return tablero;
    }

    //Define el jugador y la ficha que usará
    private void Jugador(String ficha, String jugador) {
        this.ficha = ficha;
        this.jugador = jugador;
    }

    //Sustituye el contenido del tablero por las fichas del jugador que toque 
    protected void Rellenar() {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduce datos " + jugador);

        System.out.print("Columna: ");
        fila=reader.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Fila: ");
        columna=reader.nextInt();

        tablero[columna][fila] = ficha;


        for (int col=0; col<tablero.length; col++) {
            for (int fil=0; fil<tablero.length; fil++) {
                System.out.print(tablero[col][fil]+" ");
            }
        System.out.println("");}
    }

    //Este es el método que no sé cómo seguir
    //Recorre el array horizontalmente
    protected void Comprobar() {

        for (int columna=0; columna<tablero.length; columna++) {
            for (int fila=0; fila<tablero.length; fila++) {
                if (tablero[columna][fila].equals(ficha)) {
                    System.out.println("Has ganado");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Juego jugar = new Juego();
        jugar.CrearTablero();

        for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
            jugar.Jugador("x", "Jugador1");
            jugar.Rellenar();
            jugar.Jugador("o", "Jugador2");
            jugar.Rellenar();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esas comprobaciones pero, rápidamente sería así...

**Método Comprobar():**

```
protected boolean Comprobar() {

        boolean haGanado = false;
        boolean punto1 = false;
        boolean punto2 = false;
        boolean punto3 = false;

        for (int fila = 0; fila < tablero.length; fila++) {

            for (int columna = 0; columna < tablero.length; columna++) {

                // Columna 1
                if (columna == 0 && tablero[fila][columna].equals(ficha)) {
                    punto1 = true;
                }

                // Columna 2
                else if (columna == 1 && tablero[fila][columna].equals(ficha)) {
                    punto2 = true;
                }

                // Columna 3
                else if (columna == 2 && tablero[fila][columna].equals(ficha)) {
                    punto3 = true;
                }

            }

            // Si todas son verdaderas entonces, ha ganado
            if (punto1 && punto2 && punto3) {
                System.out.println("Has ganado");
                haGanado = true; // Enviar que ha ganado
                return haGanado; // Salir del for y enviar resultado
            }
        }

        return haGanado; // Enviar resultado
    }
```

Notar que he cambiado `tablero[columna][fila]...` por `tablero[fila][columna]...`.

**Main:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Juego jugar = new Juego();
        jugar.CrearTablero();

        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            jugar.Jugador("x", "Jugador1");
            jugar.Rellenar();

            // Comprobar
            if (jugar.Comprobar()) {
                return; // Salir del for
            }

            jugar.Jugador("o", "Jugador2");
            jugar.Rellenar();

            // Comprobar
            if (jugar.Comprobar()) {
                return; // Salir del for
            }
        }
    }
```

Espero haberte ayudado.